# Infinite order group that has no nontrivial subgroup?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Is there any infinite order group that has no nontrivial subgroup?

I guess there isn't, but I don't know how to approach.

Answer (score 5):

Any infinite group has a nontrivial subgroup. If the group is not cyclic, take the cyclic subgroup generated by any nonidentity element. If it is cyclic with generator $a$, take the subgroup generated by $a^2$.

Answer (score 4):

Pick an element $g \ne e$. If it has finite order, you're done.

If not, consider $H = \{ g^{2n} | n \in \mathbb Z\}$.